# How to provide multilanguage support for an Android Application

Tags: android

I want to develop an Android application in which I will display a menu for language selection, in which the user can select a languge . My application is supposed to be done for English and Arabic language. How to develop an application in a language other than english in Android. What are the steps I need to follow to develop an application in Arabic Language in Android. Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 5):

You localize your application using standard Android localization as described in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html.

As for selecting the current language, you shouldn't create your own UI for modifying the current locale, rather let the user change the global settings with something like:

```
Intent languageSettingsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
languageSettingsIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");            
startActivity(languageSettingsIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement a particular language menu. Android has built-in mechanism of localization. You [them](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: No,my application has to be developed to English and Arabic language.According to specification,I have to develop a screen where the user can select English or Arabic language.If he selects Arabic language, then how should I enable arabic Strings

Comment: My advice is to learn more about built-in mechanism and to discuss it with your customer. The language menu is not the common beahviour for android platform.